# Orchard Excedption: The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available

Tags: html, css, orchardcms

I am working in some widget in orchard. I created new site using orchard and added the widget in it. then I changed the theme to make the website look different.

Once I did it, I got the following error. I dont know why it came and how to rectify it.

**The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available.**

I stopped the IIS express and reloaded the project. later I closed the VS2013 and re-run the project, nothing helped.

Can any one say me why I got that error???

Comment: Thats the same thing. The example has the same amount of text in it so it lines up, if you take some of the text out it will not be equal anymore..

Comment: What do you want them to do? 1aside` should changed height based on what `layout-content` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
#layout-main {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#aside-first {
    display: table-cell;
    width:28%;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:#5276BC;
}
#layout-content {
    display: table-cell;
    width:70%;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:#5276BC;
}
```

Also, check the [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wTqtJ/2/)